# How to create a directory in SFTP using Talend

Tags: talend

Is there any component in Talend that can create a Directory in FTP?

I need to copy the files from one directory in FTP to another Directory(New) in FPT, For that i need to create a new Directory?

Comment: This is not a good question and will most likely be removed from the website if you don't put in some effort to improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use Tssh component in Talend and use unix command to create directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tFTPCreateDirectory 0.2 from Talend marketplace.

Marc

Comment: You can download this Component here:  https://exchange.talend.com/#marketplaceproductreviews:gallery=marketplace%252F1&pi=marketplace%252F1%252Fproducts%252F666%252Fitems%252F976